# How to get wooCommerce Order id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to get wooCommerce order id. I wrote the following script in functions.php but i getting 0.Can you tell how to get the Id.

```
global $woocommerce, $post;
  $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
  $order_id=$order->get_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get order id by this function. `get_order_number()`
You can use the code given below.

```
global $woocommerce, $post;
$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
$order_id = $order->get_order_number();
```

You can check additional documentation from this [link](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order.html).

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
$order_data = wc_get_order( $order_id );
echo $order_data->get_id();
```

How you are calling the above code(like hook) in functions.php...